# Update one/multiple boolean column ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview, insert-update

I want to update a **Boolean bound column** in gridview without adding any

> Command Type : Edit Column to grid

I want to update it in grid directly. its not important if its server side or client side, I can update immediately after user **check/unchecked** the radioButton/Checkbox.

I have searched lot, but can't find anything?

Help Please.

Comment: Do you want to add column ? on check/uncheck... or you want to update single cell ?

Comment: I just want to have a editable checkbox bound to DB and just update that, but in some grids, its only one row , and in some others , there are multiple rows.